# Mapreduce WordCount Example giving wrong output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I am trying to learn mapreduce. While starting from the WordCount Example as shown in [MapReduce WordCount](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html), when I execute the code in eclipse, it's output was correct word count. I/p File content was as follows:-

> Hello World Bye World

It's output was

> Bye 1
>
> Hello 1
>
> World 2

After that I test the code by replacing the space with comma after each word in the input file.

Now I have reverted the input to same as before but now WordCount in the output is double of the expected result.

> Bye 2
>
> Hello 2
>
> World 4

My Code is as below:

```
public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text,IntWritable>{
    public static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()){
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}

public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        int sum=0;
        for(IntWritable val:values){
            sum +=val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] str) throws Exception{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    
   FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(str[0]));
   FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(str[1]));
   
   System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    
    
}
```

Can anybody also explain how values are grouped by for each word in Reducer Method as it's doing sum of each value for the specific word.Where it's checking that two counts are there for the same word.

Thanks

Comment: delete the tmp file in the same input folder :)

Comment: @vefthym Yes you were right. There was a tmp file created. Can you please let me know why this tmp file was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must be given input folder as an input path in which you must have two files with same content and that might be reason for double count

Comment: that's true that i am giving input folder as path but there is only one file.

Comment: Yes you were correct .Other file was not being shown through UI. When i checked through terminal it was there with name "file01~". I deleted it and now it's working. Can you let me know why this file was created there. Also can you help me with my other question in the post.

Comment: I have tries your code and it gives me right result, just try to give  file path instead of folder path as input

Comment: Values are grouped in reducer as per key , in this program you configured word as key in mapper so reducer got key wise records and reduce method get called for each key, so in your case reduce method call thrice for Hello,Bye and World, so for Hello your key and value array is like (Hello,[1]) for Bye it is like (Bye,[1]) and for World it is like (World,[1,1])